# How to read one character at a time from user input — at each keystroke (without waiting for the user to press the return key)?

Tags: ocaml

I'm looking for something like `input_char stdin` but without waiting for a return key. I would not to depend on a big dependency like lambda-term.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Handling input in full lines is easy. Handling it a character at a time is a little bit system dependent. If you're on a Unix-like system you should be able to do this using the `Unix` module:

```
let get1char () =
    let termio = Unix.tcgetattr Unix.stdin in
    let () =
        Unix.tcsetattr Unix.stdin Unix.TCSADRAIN
            { termio with Unix.c_icanon = false } in
    let res = input_char stdin in
    Unix.tcsetattr Unix.stdin Unix.TCSADRAIN termio;
    res
```