# OCaml read pressed key without graphical window

Tags: keyboard, ocaml, windows-console

Edit. I am working in a Windows environment.

I want to write a simple game in console output with OCaml. I need to be able to use a 'read_key' function. But :

- The graphics module throws an error : `Exception: Graphics.Graphic_failure "graphic screen not opened".` But I do not want to open the graphic window.
- The function `read_line` forces the user to press "return" after every key press...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a character in OCaml without a return key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410159/how-to-read-a-character-in-ocaml-without-a-return-key)

Comment: @gallais : I just tried it, but as I am working in a windows environment, it did not solve my problem... Exception: Invalid_argument "Unix.tcgetattr not implemented".

Comment: @RUser4512 it would help us next time if you mention that you're on windows from the beginning.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian thank you, this is fixed now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to implement such function using pure OCaml. You will need to call to platform specific libraries. It is not an OCaml problem, this is the same for other languages, including python, java, c, etc. Actually, interacting with a terminal in a portable way is kind of rocket science. Mostly for historical reasons.

I suspect, that you don't want to get into such troubles, so I can suggest few easy solutions:

1. Use [OCamlSDL](http://ocamlsdl.sourceforge.net/doc/html/index.html) library, - you're developing a game, and SDL is for games
2. Use Graphics module, yes you will need to open the graphic window, and your game will not be a pure console... but maybe this is not a big issue. Also, you can make a black background and emulate a terminal :)
3. Install Cygwin version of OCaml. You will get a unix-like environment, and `Unix.tc_*` will start to work.
4. Switch to a normal operating system. Where by normal I mean Unix-like. You can use virtual machine, or containers, like Docker, for a first time.

Comment: Thanks ! I wished I could have something that runs seemlessly on Windows and Unix environments, without requiring too many libraries. Cygwin & virtual machines will require the user (some) efforts... I may end up implementing solution 2 :)