# Ocaml how to get keyboard event

Tags: ocaml

how can I get event from keyboard in Ocaml ? For example I need to get the two directional arrow ( left and right), how can I get that ?

Comment: This is generally a system-dependent thiing. You might look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36089021/ocaml-read-pressed-key-without-graphical-window

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OCaml read pressed key without graphical window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36089021/ocaml-read-pressed-key-without-graphical-window)