# Read bytes from the standard input when they're written

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to read from the standard input by using `input_byte stdin`

Something like this:

```ml
let rec loop () =
  Format.eprintf "in the loop@.";
  (match input_byte stdin with
  | 0x0D -> print_newline ()
  | b -> Format.eprintf "saw %i@." b);
  loop ()

let () =
  loop ()
```

If I type `aaa` I expect to see

```
in the loop
a
in the loop
saw 97
a
in the loop
saw 97
a
in the loop
saw 97
```

But instead nothing happens until I hit enter and this is what I have:

```
in the loop
aaa
saw 97
in the loop
saw 97
in the loop
saw 97
in the loop
saw 10
in the loop
```

Is there a way to read characters from a channel with a reader that doesn't wait for a flush?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking the terminal driver of your system doesn't send characters at each keystroke. As you're seeing, it waits to send a whole line. This is more efficient and it also lets you correct errors before sending.

There are system-dependent ways to change this buffering behavior (and also echoing behavior, which you might also want to change). If you're on some kind of Unix system (anything but Windows essentially) you can use `Unix.tcsetattr` to change the handling of characters by the terminal driver.

Here is a previous question and answer that shows how to read one character at a time: [How to read a character in OCaml without a return key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410159/how-to-read-a-character-in-ocaml-without-a-return-key/13410456?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C29.1473#13410456)

Comment: Ah, thanks! I had set i_echo to false but not i_canon!